# tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename slow to save a file

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I noticed that tkinter filedialog asksaveasfilename takes 3 seconds or more to save a file. is it normal? is there  a way to make it faster? (notepad or notepad ++ are faster than it)
Python 3.7

example

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.filedialog
import tkinter.scrolledtext


class app:

    def __init__(self):
        self._root= tkinter.Tk()
        self._root.grid()
        self._text= tkinter.Text(self._root)
        self._text.grid()
        self.menubar = tkinter.Menu(self._root)
        self.filemenu  = tkinter.Menu(self.menubar) 
        self.filemenu.add_command(label="Salva", command=self._save)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.filemenu) 
        self._root.config(menu=self.menubar)

    def _save(self):
        path = tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(title="Save")
        if len(path) > 0:
            with open(path, "w") as f:
                f.write(self._text.get("1.0", "end-1c"))

    def show(self):
        self._root.mainloop()

a=app()
a.show()
```

Comment: I tried your code and it literally finished in an instant. Did you paste some amount of text in your widget?

Comment: @Henry Yik thanks anyway I solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the provided code and it was saving the file in sub-millisecond time.
Did you use a time function to check the time it took to save? If you did you must make sure to mark the start time before you ask the user for the file location, otherwise it will include the time it takes for the user to pick the file location they want.

```
def _save(self):

    # Do Not Start timer here
    path = tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(title="Save")

    # Start timer here
    start = time.time()

    if len(path) > 0:
        with open(path, "w") as f:
            f.write(self._text.get("1.0", "end-1c"))

    print(time.time() - start)
```

Comment: MatthewGadsden Thanks